# For a small MongoDB collection, is it safe to design as if it's all in memory?

Tags: session, mongodb

There are many uses of MongoDB for which I would like to treat a collection as if it's in memory.   For example, for a collection of user Session objects (for a website).  Prior to using MongoDB, I would store such data in a memcached server, etc.  But, it seems silly to have to run both memcached+MongoDB for cases like this.

Is it reasonably safe to assume that for a small-sized (small ~= 1% of total system RAM) collection of frequently accessed data, that the collection is essentially always held in-memory?  I'm always going to be doing direct lookup by _id, and have no indexes on the data.

Would it help this assumption if the Session collection were held in its own database?  I ask because of the nature of MongoDB's buffer cache based memory mapping scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't do DB storage memory management itself but relies on OS virtual memory manager. So it's very dependent on OS. The VMM can load the whole DB in memory, even if it 99% of its size, or it can page it all out because other applications are demanding RAM. So it also depends on usage patterns.

Any decent VMM will try to keep MRU data in memory whenever possible, so your Session collection will likely be always in memory no matter whether it's in separate database or not - it's split into pages (usually of 4k size).

You can always check paging status with `mongostat` utility. It has page fault counter which represents number of accesses to pages that were not in memory and had to be loaded from file.

Comment: My thought about keeping it in a separate database was that if I mix my Session collection with the rest of my data, then I might have only 1 session object per page, mixed with a bunch of other random objects from other collections.  If I put the Session in it's own DB, then each 4k page of that DB will be filled with Session objects.  But, I'm not sure how mongodb assigns collection objects to pages, so I don't know if this matters or not.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is fine to be keeping big collections in memory, as long as you control your collections for memory leak (e.g., unused objects are eventually released). The reason why this is not a problem is that any server these days has virtual memory, where the unused pages are being swapped to. This way, even if memory is allocated for some objects which are not used often, performance of the system will not suffer.